# Django Rest collecting multiple records into a list

Tags: json, django, api, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a restaurant app and I am making use of serializers to create the api for it. I have a restaurant table and a phone number table. The phone number table references the restaurant_id as a foreign key. Similarly there are other relationships of this sort. I wrote a serializer like this:

```
class RestaurantOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand = BrandSerializer()
    numbers = PhoneNumberSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('brand', 'address', 'id', 'numbers')
```

What this gives is a nested structure. While in some cases useful over here it becomes unnecessary because `PhoneNumberSerializer` has a single field. Is there a way to collapse the nesting into a single field for a simpler json?

From this:

```
{
    "restaurant_name": "Blah Blah:
     ...

    "numbers": {
                 {
                  "number": 123
                },{
                  "number": 456
                  }
                }
}
```

To:

```
{
"restaurant_name": "Blah Blah:
...
"numbers": ["123", "456"]

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `numbers` be a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already wrote your own serializer, which you do not need in this case. You can use the StringRelatedField(many=True).

```
from rest_framework import serializers 
class RestaurantOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand = BrandSerializer()
    numbers = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `to_representation()` method to achieve this.

> If you need to alter the serialization, deserialization or validation
>   of a serializer class you can do so by overriding the
>   `.to_representation()` or `.to_internal_value()` methods.

You need to do something like:

```
class RestaurantOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    brand = BrandSerializer()
    numbers = PhoneNumberSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('brand', 'address', 'id', 'numbers')

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        # get the default representation
        serialized_data = super(RestaurantOrderSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        numbers = serialized_data['numbers'] 
        serialized_data['numbers'] = [x['number'] for x in numbers] # list of numbers
        return serialized_data
```